# Back button isn't getting displayed upon pushing a controller into the stack

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I created iOS application from **Navigation-based application** template.
This snippet is from RootViewController.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  DotoViewController *detailViewController = [[DotoViewController alloc] 
                             initWithNibName:@"DotoViewController" bundle:nil];
  NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] 
                             objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  detailViewController.dotoObj = selectedObject;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
  [detailViewController release];   
}
```

DotoViewController is a subclass of UIViewController and has an accompanying NIB file.

Upong clicking on a row, DotoViewController is getting displayed but without the back button to RootViewController on the left side.

What I'm missing?

Comment: What's in your root view controller's `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @BoltClock I didn't touch RootViewController's viewDidLoad , it contains the default code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps your root view controller has an empty title? The view controller's title is used as the title for the back button, so if you have an empty string there, this can cause the back button to disappear. If it's nil, it should display the standard "Back" though.

Comment: OMG !! You are right, I set a string to RootViewController and every thing is working !! :) I have spent the last three hours trying to figure what is going wrong. Thank you from the heart.

Comment: I think the generated code should setting RootViewController's title to any thing in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Seconded. I don't have a title displayed for my root view controller, so didn't think about setting a title, and was baffled why I couldn't get the back button to automatically show.